# Can someone explain this bitwise array-wrap-around expression?

Tags: python, algorithm, word-wrap

I've been researching on the Diamond-square algorithm and I came across [this website](http://www.bluh.org/code-the-diamond-square-algorithm/) which pointed me to the source code of Notch's Minicraft, and does a conversion of the algorithm as was implemented by Notch.

For the most part I understand the algorithm, but I can get my head around the specific expression found in these two functions:

```java
private double sample(int x, int y) {
    return values[ (x & (w - 1)) + (y & (h - 1)) * w ];
}

private void setSample(int x, int y, double value) {
    values[ (x & (w - 1)) + (y & (h - 1)) * w ] = value;
}
```

I do understand `x + y * w`, but not `(x & (w - 1)) + (y & (h - 1)) * w`, and the article doesn't explain this besides stating that it serves to wrap-around.

I'm coding in python, but I don't think there's any difference between Java's bitwise `&` and python's, so I fiddled with it a bit but I still can't get it. One of the things I did was a loop that simulates varying `x` and `y` values and feeds them to that calculation:

```py
import random
w = h = 257     # 2^8 + 1
for i in xrange(10):
    x = int(random.uniform(0, 1) *255)
    y = int(random.uniform(0, 1) *255)

    print x, y, '|', (x & (w-1)) + (y & (h-1)) *w

    # I used a less readable right-aligning version of the above to display the output:
    # print str( x ).rjust(3), str( y ).rjust(3), '|', str( (x & (w-1)) + (y & (h-1)) * w ).rjust(3)
```

Output:

```
112 213 |   0
181 117 |   0
  1 105 |   0
216 223 |   0
170 185 |   0
158  32 |   0
124 225 |   0
 62 153 |   0
 90 147 |   0
196  69 |   0
```

Unless I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here, it always gives me zero, unless `x` and/or `y` are equal to `w-1`, in which case:

```
256  15 |   256
 21 256 | 65792
256 256 | 66048
```

In the actual algorithm the value of `x` and `y` seems to always be (if I understand correctly) somewhere between `0` and `halfStep`, where `halfStep = stepSize/2`, `stepSize = featureSise` which seems to be (in Minicraft's code) always hardcoded as `16` or `32`. So according to my current understanding that expression would always evaluate to `0`.

So I'm confused. I don't see how this is useful or how it actually works in practice... I know it works, but it seems like sorcery... 
I understand how the bitwise `&` works, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: To obtain a uniform random integer use `random.randint` instead of using `uniform` and multiplying. The result is always zero because you have `w=h=257` which means that `w-1` is `256` which is `0b100000000`. The numbers `x` and `y` are between `0` and `255`, so have only 8 bits and thus the `&` will always result in `0`.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to have the width and height to be `257`? My guess would be that you should use something more like `w=h=128`... Also note that having `w=h=256` wont do anything because then `w-1=255` which is `0b11111111` and so the `&` is just the identity.

Comment: @Bakuriu That makes sense, but the upper bounds `w` and `h` will always have more bits even if they're 128, thus, at least in that loop I made, the result is still always `0`. `x` and `y` are always a subdivision of them. The reason why I'm not using `^2`, but `^2+1` is that the algorithm works only with odd numbers (specifically powers of two + 1, according to what I've been reading)

Comment: @Bakuriu Actually, after reading both your comments and Michael Hoff's answer I realized, if I do it with 255 (`x & 255`) it always gives me a number between `0` and `255`, even if `x > 255`. That's makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`w` and `h` must be powers of 2 (and represent the local bounds for `x` and `y`, respectively).
Then, `w-1` and `h-1` are sequences of ones. One for each bit of information which could possibly contribute to a value lower than `w` and `h` (and still be `>= 0`), respectively.

When you now evaluate the bit-wise *and* (`&`), e.g. `x & (w-1)`, this will actually yield `x % w`, where `%` is the modulo operation in python, for `x >= 0`.
Thus, `x` is mapped to `x` if `w > x >= 0` and otherwise `x` is truncated (zeroing higher bits), such that `w > x >= 0` is satisfied.
The same applies to `y` and `h`.

Consequently, these logical operations are nothing more than evaluating *mod* on a bit-level.

For your code: Set `w=h=256` and everything should work out.

Comment: The `&` operator is not "logical and". It's a "bitwise" operator. The logical (or Boolean) operator is `and`. I'd also clarify that it's the high-bits of `x` that get "truncated" (normally with that term I would expect it to be the low bits getting cut).

Comment: Thank you. I updated the answer. I think "truncate" is okay in this context, as the interval is also stated in the same sentence. Nevertheless, I added a short hint.

Comment: @MichaelHoff Thanks for your answer. I realized now that if `w` is `255`, the output will be between `0` and `255`. That makes more sense. So this means `w` may be `256` (or `n^8`); I got the idea it was `n^8+1` because, as far as I understand, the diamond-square algorithm needs odd numbers, so that there's a middle point to be found between other points. I'm a bit confused on that part now, but at least this part seems to make more sense now.